# How to handle exception in vertx consumer?

Tags: java, vert.x

I have code:

```
SqlTemplate
    .forQuery(client, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id=#{id}")
    .execute(parameters)
    .onSuccess(users -> {
      users.forEach(row -> {
        // exception here
        System.out.println(row.get(UUID.class, "id1") + " " + row.getString("title"));
      });
    })
```

What is the best way to handle exceptions in consumers?
For now if exception raises it will be swallowed...

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to fail the flow when an exception is thrown, it is better to use compose to iterate through the users and handle `.onSuccess()` and `.onFailure()` separately.

You can use `CompositeFuture` to achieve this. You can have a Future list and add succeededFuture / failedFuture (in case of exception) to the list in the `forEach` loop.

```
SqlTemplate
    .forQuery(client, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id=#{id}")
    .execute(parameters)
    .compose(users -> {
      List<Future> usersFuture = new ArrayList<>();
      users.forEach(row -> {
        try {
          // exception here
          System.out.println(row.get(UUID.class, "id1") + " " + row.getString("title"));
          usersFuture.add(Future.succeededFuture());
        } catch (Exception e) {
          usersFuture.add(Future.failedFuture(e));
        }
      });
      return CompositeFuture.all(usersFuture).mapEmpty();
    })
    .onSuccess(res -> { 
        // end the flow with success
    })
    .onFailure(e -> { 
        // Add error message and fail the flow
    });
```

Also in general I'm curious about the exceptions that can be thrown here. As it is the data that you have written to your db after validations, you should be aware of the possible error scenarios and handle them accordingly without failing the flow.